# I want to share Solution to: #1142 - La commande 'INSERT, DELETE' est interdite à l'utilisateur: ''@'@localhost' sur la table 'pma_recent'?

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

Open the config.inc.php file from C:\xampp\phpmyadmin

Put the "//" characters in config.inc.php at the start of below line:

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';

Example: // $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';

Reload your phpmyadmin at localhost.

Answer (score 0):

While that works to eliminate the error message, it completely disables the phpMyAdmin Configuration Storage feature. A better solution is to properly configure this table and your 'controluser'. From the error message, it appears as if the user defined in `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser']` doesn't have the proper permissions.

Use the command `GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON <pma_db>.* TO 'pma'@'localhost'  IDENTIFIED BY 'pmapass';` substituting the proper database name for `<pma_db>`, username instead of `pma`, and password instead of `pmapass`.

It might be instead that your database structure isn't quite right, which you can resolve by running the `create_tables.sql` which can be found in the `sql/` or `examples/` folder within your phpMyAdmin installation.